# DataTables taking a long time to load/timing out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, jquery, static-resources, datatables.js

Is there anything about the following Datatables code that would cause a timeout or cause issues with the construction of a datatable?

First, I have jquery, bootstrap, jqueryui, datables, and moment.js as static resources in our salesforce org. I'm importing them to my aura component with the following code:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!join(',',  
                      $Resource.bootstrapjqueryui,
                      $Resource.datatables + '/DataTables-1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css',
                      $Resource.datatablesSLDS )}"
              scripts="{!join(',', 
                       $Resource.jquery224, $Resource.bootstrap411 + '/bootstrap-5.1.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                       $Resource.jqueryui + '/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js',
                       $Resource.datatables + '/datatables.min.js',
                       $Resource.datatables + '/DataTables-1.11.3/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js',
                       $Resource.datatables + '/DataTables-1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
                       $Resource.moment)}"/>
```

Then an init method fires that contains the following code block:

```
 $.fn.dataTable.moment('M/D/YYYY');
        var table = $('#suiteproducts').DataTable( {
            destroy: true,
            scrollY: 200,
            data : dataSet,
            select : 'single',
            pagination : true,
            search : true,
            columns : [
                { data: "event", title : "Event Name" },
                { data: "eventdate", title : "Event Date" },
                { data: "suite", title : "Suite" },
                { data: "hometeam", title : "Home Team" },
                { data: "opposingteam", title : "Opposing Team" },
                { data: "status", title : "Status" },
                { data: "heldfor", title : "Held For/Account Name" }
            ],
            initComplete : function () {
                this.api()
                .column(5)
                .data()
                .unique()
                .each(function ( d, j ) {
                    $('#status').append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
                component.set('v.spinner', false);
                
            },
            "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                if ( data.contractelement == contractElementId ) {
                    $('td', row).addClass('table-primary-permanent');
                }
            }
        } );
```

The issue is that once the code reaches this block, it either 1) takes 45-60 seconds to load and display the datatable, or 2) The code never completes, or 3) chrome times out.

I Inherited this project from a previous dev and I have very low experience with Datatables, moment and jquery. Is there anything basic that I'm missing/ that could be causing datatables to fail?

here is the data option parameter:

```
dataSet.push({
            'id' : result[i].Id,
            'contractelement' : (result[i].Contract_Element__c || ''),
            'event' : (result[i].MSE_Event__r.Name || ''), 
            'suite' : (result[i].Suite__r.Name || ''), 
            'hometeam' : (result[i].Home_Team__c || ''),
            'gamecolor' : (result[i].Game_Color__c || ''),
            'opposingteam' : (result[i].Opposing_Team__c || ''),
            'eventdate' : (moment(result[i].Event_Date__c).format('M/D/YYYY') || ''),
            'status' : (result[i].Status__c || ''),
            'recordtype' : (result[i].RecordType.Name || ''),
            'heldfor' : (result[i].Account_Held_For__c || '')
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT: I'm going to mark this a solved, our issue was a large dataset**

Comment: Usually when something that works like DataTables is causing the browser to crash it's because it's attempting to manipulate too many DOM nodes at once. How much data is being shown in this table and if you can cut the table down to something small (say a few dozen records) do you get any noticeable improvement? One thing that does strike me as being poorly optimized in the code is the loop with `append` in it. You'd be better off adding all of the options to the DOM at one time. I would also check that interactions with the Lightning framework isn't causing the table to re-render repeatedly.

Comment: In our QA org we have about 8000 records, cutting down the records to 50 DID get it to load pretty quickly. Thanks for the info on the append function. Would you be able to explain in more detail how I might go about adding all of the options to the DOM at the same time? If not, would you be able to point me in the direction of some more info? Thanks so much for any more insight!

Comment: See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111740/jquery-appending-an-array-of-elements. When you update the DOM, that's an expensive operation for the browser to make so consolidating changes can give you performance boosts but it sounds like in your case it's the _amount_ of data in the table that's slowing it down. I would not render more than a few hundred records at a time for that reason. What is the use case for showing so many records? Also, check how you're adding elements to the dataset too. The `dataSet.push` code looks to be adding them one by one.

Comment: Gotcha. Our use case is to load all of the records from a specific sObject "Suite_Products__c", display them to the user on screen, and allow the user to select different filter options to find the record that they want to select and ultimately attach to a parent sObject.

Comment: You probably want to implement a pagination method / component to limit the mount of data you are loading in the table. we had the same issue when loading around 1k records. paginating the results and limiting the amount of displayed data is the way to go in lightning.

Comment: Our table is paginated to the end user, only showing 5 rows per page. But I think the table is loaded up with all 8000 of our records in order for the end user to be able to sort and filter instantly. Its actually really strange because it's worked fine for 3 years and it just suddenly stopped working last week out of nowhere with no change to the codebase on our end.